# Fine Uploaders deleteComplete event hook

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

being not that much of a js guy using http://fineuploader.com/demos.html gave me a good headstart getting fineuploader working in the citadel webinterface. 
My last issue which I fail to achieve is getting a deleteComplete hook registered (as documented here: http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/events.html#deleteComplete )
I'm probably missing some domain specific vocabulary, so my general question is, how does one specify event handlers, the deleteComplete one in specific.

My need is to call update_attachment_count() which should refresh the number of attachments uploaded for the mail being composed in the main screen.

so far I've got (we don't use jquery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createUploader()
{
    var uploader = new qq.FineUploader(
    {
        session: {
        endpoint: "do_template?template=edit_message_json_attlist"
        },
        callbacks: {
        onComplete: update_attachment_count,
        delete: update_attachment_count,
        deleteComplete: update_attachment_count
        },
        element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
        request: {
        endpoint: 'upload_attachment?nonce=<?NONCE>&template=edit_message_upl_att'
        },
        deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        forceConfirm: true,
        endpoint: 'remove_attachment?nonce=<?NONCE>&template=edit_message_upl_att&which_attachment='
        }
    });
}

  window.onload = createUploader;
</script>
<div id="fine-uploader"></div>
...
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function update_attachment_count() {
        p = 'r=' + CtdlRandomString();
        new Ajax.Updater(
            'num_attachments',
            'show_num_attachments',
            {
                method: 'get',
                parameters: p
            }
        );
    }

</script>
</div>
```

TIA, and thanks a lot for making Fineuploader available.

Comment: We've added some additional clarification to the documentation.  Please have a look and let us know if there is anything else we can improve in this area.

Comment: Yes, this makes it clear. I guess what I was missing was the bridge between 'callback' and 'events'. The snippets solve this in a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you're trying to do exactly with the event handlers, but here is the correct syntax for the three you specified above.

```
// ...
callbacks: {
    onComplete: function (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {
        console.log("Upload completed for fileid: " + id);
    }
    onDelete: function (id) {
        console.log("About to send delete request for fileid: " + id);
    },
    onDeleteComplete: function (id, xhr, isError) {
        console.log("Deletion completed for fileid: " + id);
    }
},
// ...
```

For jQuery events, see [FineUploader OnComplete not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478100/fineuploader-oncomplete-not-being-called).

[Need FineUploader Method uploadStoredFiles to Complete Before Proceeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506840/need-fineuploader-method-uploadstoredfiles-to-complete-before-proceeding/20556260#20556260) will get you started on updating the UI based on the number of uploads (attachments).

Comment: thanks a lot, this was the missing link to me. Maybe you can add it to your examples for others to find ;-)

Comment: @dothebart All of the demos on the homepage include this syntax, as well as the jQuery-specific syntax for registering event handlers.  Also, the getting started guide in the documentation is another place that uses this syntax.  We can add a note on the events page as well though.